# How should I lay out cards for print?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, layout

i'm in the process of making a deck of flashcards, there's around a hundred of them. the image on each card and it's corresponding back is different.
what is the most efficient way to prep my cards for printing on the office's xerox machine?

should I be laying them out on multiple A3 artboards? is there an efficient method to laying them out in the same manner or would i have to manually place and position every image in ai?

Comment: All you really need to do is lay out one artboard and repeat that.

Comment: For an automatic solution, you would need some type of imposition software. This could be added onto InDesign, Acrobat, or a standalone product. Unfortunately, I do not think Adobe has this built into their programs.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option "Multiple Pages Per Sheet" in the print menu. I think this works from acrobat, indesign or illustrator.
Be careful that the double sided print is on and set correctly, otherwise it will flip the back side and therefore the cards get jumbled...